# Concatenating linked lists while maintaining fast head node lookup

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I have a program in C that relies on (circularly) linked lists and needs fast head lookup. The obvious thing to do is to maintain a pointer to the head for each element of the list. However, there are a lot of these linked lists and they are being concatenated. Using a naive implementation with pointers to the head nodes is too slow since I need to walk through one linked list and update all of the head node pointers every time I want to concatenate a pair. Is there a more clever data structure, or some pointer/indirection trick that will allow each element to maintain fast head node lookup when concatenating lists?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are doing. What is "maintain a pointer to the head for each element of the list?". Is "the head" the first element in the list?

Comment: Does each element have a pointer to the first element?

Comment: If yes, then you are right that maintaining a pointer in *each* element is too much work, and also too much storage wasted. Why does it have to be a linked list after all? The tradeoffs are well known. What about trees? Union-Find? Arrays? Please indicate *what* you want to do!

Comment: How are you implementing the basic list concatenation? Do you maintain a pointer to the tail of the list, are you using a doubly linked circular list, or something else? Without fast access to the tail your algorithm will need to traverse both lists anyway - once to find the end of the first list, then again to link the tail of the second list back to the head of the first (to achieve the circularity requirement). Updating the head pointers as you traverse should not have a massive impact - the algorithm still has O(n) complexity.

Comment: Some details regarding your implementation, objective, and data might be helpful. Some obvious shortcuts can be suggested, but possibly another data structure would be better.

Comment: Does a circular linked list even have a head node?